# What USB speed in 2019 Buick Regal?

Tags: buick, regal, universal-serial-bus

What data speed does the 2019 Buick Regal TourX have on its USB-A data ports?

For example, USB 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 3.2?

[image: inside the arm console of a 2019 Buick Regal]

There's no mention of a speed or USB spec in the [Getting to Know](https://www.buick.com/bypass/pcf/gma-content-api/resources/sites/GMA/content/staging/MANUALS/4000/MA4833/en_US/7.0/GTK_2019_Buick_Regal_TourX_84414198_A.pdf) guide, [Infotainment Manual](https://www.buick.com/bypass/pcf/gma-content-api/resources/sites/GMA/content/staging/MANUALS/4000/MA4334/en_US/1.0/19_BUI_IM_en_US_U_84134605B_2018JUL03_2P.pdf) or [Owner's Manual](https://www.buick.com/bypass/pcf/gma-content-api/resources/sites/GMA/content/staging/MANUALS/4000/MA4333/en_US/2.0/19_BUI_Regal_OM_en_US_U_84221878B_2018NOV27_2P.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What color is the inside of the terminal? That should give you a clue.

Comment: I'm not looking at my actual vehicle right now. Based on the photos in the manual, the ports appear to be black.

Comment: From what I'm seeing in an online search, most vehicles still use USB 2.0 ... I don't know that for fact, though.

Comment: I can't imagine why a manufacturer would spend money on USB-3 in a car. Nor why it would be relevant at this point in time.

Comment: (1) CarPlay uses much more bandwidth than audio, and I’ve been having latency issues. (2) I’m buying new USB cables, and I don’t want to over- or under-spend.